# User Edits: Profile says one thing, Users tab says another

Tags: support, edits, profile-page, top-users

I've just noticed there's a difference between the number of user edits listed in user profiles versus in the Users page.

**Exhibit A**

[image]

**Exhibit B**

[image]

A difference of 1,826 edits is too large to blame caching for... so what is one tab counting that the other isn't?

Comment: If I had  to guess, I'd say deleted posts.

Comment: @CodyGray It could be. I do find it odd, however, that the "xxx votes cast" counts votes on deleted posts, but edits don't.

Comment: And [the revision tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/cs95?tab=activity&sort=revisions) shows a third number (11k atm)

Comment: @Zoe edits =/= revisions. Edits are counted once per post, but you can do multiple revisions per post

Comment: The user has edited 4633 posts a total of 6459 times.

Comment: More accurately, "edited posts" != "edits"

Comment: I didn't even consider that you could interpret amount of edits to mean amount of edited posts. I mean, isn't it a common case that a post is edited multiple times?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene) has [explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298672/165483) on Meta Stack Exchange, that the "posts edited" number on the profile's Impact box refers to (non-deleted) posts of other users that you edited **at least once** (*tag-only edits excluded*); while the number of edits on the editors page are the number of **unique revisions** you made on other users' posts (everything - rollbacks, title, retags included).

Also this corroborates with ex-employee [waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/17174/waffles)' [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122489/165483) on Meta Stack Exchange, that the count on the editors page "also counts posts that were simply retagged".

Comment: And the revisions tab likely shows revisions made on other users' + your own posts, hence it shows an even larger number.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399359/4284627) the Impact box doesn't count tag-only edits, which isn't clear from your answer. Maybe you should edit your answer to make that more clear.

Comment: @DonaldDuck done, thanks