# How is it possible that a user has more edits this week than in total?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, users

I was looking through the week's best editor, and this user was first:

[image]

But when I go into the users profile, this is what I see:

[image]

Apparently this user has **in total** 253 edits, but in a week has managed to do 3247 edits. What is going on?

Comment: Edits to one's own posts do not count IIRC, and that user has posted more than one thousand answers. I may be wrong, but it would be a change from caching ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi What do you mean? If the total amount of edits made by a user is 253, then how can they edit 3247 posts in a week? Edit: I stand corrected.

Comment: That total amount of 253 doesn't include simple re-tagging of questions. That text ("x posts edited") is a link, click it and you'll see that this user has over 5k actual edits.

Comment: Just a note: if you're going to go to the trouble to censor the username for some reason, you should probably also include the URL and user ID.

Comment: @TheWanderer Oops I forgot. I don't think it matters anyway

Comment: You redacted the first screenshot but not the second.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The vast majority of the user's edits during the past week were retags. Retags aren't shown in the user profile under the number of posts edited, but they are taken into account in the weekly leagues.

See the user's detailed edit history here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7296893/erik-a?tab=activity&sort=revisions

For context, they ran a bot that fixed the tagging on a bunch of old [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) questions. This was done with full moderator approval.

Comment: Thanks. I thought retags counted as well, because they would go through, but I was wrong :).